# Pandas returning Traceback and am not sure why

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas installed via pip, and i believe I have all of it's dependencies.  When I try to run it, I get the same error over and over again.  [Panda Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUamu.jpg)
I am not sure why I keep getting this error.  I have looked and everything seems to be ok.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page = requests.get("http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.7772&lon=-122.4168")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
seven_day = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast")
forecast_items = seven_day.find_all(class_="tombstone-container")
tonight = forecast_items[0]
period = tonight.find(class_="period-name").get_text()
short_desc = tonight.find(class_="short-desc").get_text()
temp = tonight.find(class_="temp").get_text()
img = tonight.find("img")
desc = img['title']
period_tags = seven_day.select(".tombstone-container .period-name")
periods = [pt.get_text() for pt in period_tags]
short_descs = [sd.get_text() for sd in seven_day.select(".tombstone-container .short-desc")]
temps = [t.get_text() for t in seven_day.select(".tombstone-container .temp")]
descs = [d["title"] for d in seven_day.select(".tombstone-container img")]
weather = pd.DataFrame({
    "period": periods,
    "short_desc": short_descs,
    "temp": temps,
    "desc": descs
})
print (weather)
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dependency of pytz is in incorrect version.

```
pip install pytz --upgrade
```

If it doesn't help, uninstall pytz and install pandas again:

```
pip uninstall pytz pandas
pip install pandas
```

I couldn't reproduce this error. Can you please tell Python, pandas and pytz versions?

Comment: Ya I am using Python 3.6 (I believe)  pandas: 0.19.1 pytz: 2017.3  I tried to upgrade and it said it was up to date.  I uninstalled and reinstalled pandas and I get the same error.  I am also using pycharm

Comment: It's strage as in the trace you provided there is UserDict.py, file that should not be there for any Python3.*. When it comes to Windows I would go for Anaconda

Comment: I tried Anaconda, but I use another software that got really messed up when I installed Anaconda.  I will keep looking for an answer.  Thanks for the help